# How to configure webpack to run dev server automatically

Tags: javascript, webpack

This is my config:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/js/main.js',
    watch: true,
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '../public'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "../public"),
        hot: true
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015']
            }
        }
        ]
    }
};
```

I would like to start dev server always when I enter command `webpack`. However in the official guides I could only find how to configure the dev server but not how to tell webpack to run it. Is it possible ?

Comment: According to [the docs](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server), you just run `node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server`. Or put that in your search path. Or define an alias for it. No, you won't get `webpack` to run it.

Comment: At most what you can do is write a npm script